# Plot data on dataframe based on a column id

Tags: python, plot, dataframe

I have to plot data from a dataframe in Python. My data frame is:

```
df = 
    time                                lat         lon         sessions
0   2014-05-06 06:28:01.525882+00:00    48.787982   11.383787   242
1   2014-05-06 06:28:22.530717+00:00    48.788082   11.383300   242
2   2014-05-06 06:29:48.550528+00:00    48.788043   11.382594   242
3   2014-05-06 06:30:05.554449+00:00    48.788040   11.381211   242
4   2014-05-06 06:30:17.557220+00:00    48.788188   11.381085   242
5   2014-05-06 06:30:27.559540+00:00    48.788753   11.381086   242
6   2014-05-06 13:17:46.022015+00:00    48.786922   11.337102   243
7   2014-05-06 13:17:57.023334+00:00    48.786888   11.338405   243
8   2014-05-06 13:18:07.024034+00:00    48.786746   11.339067   243
9   2014-05-06 13:18:18.025342+00:00    48.786281   11.341296   243
10  2014-05-06 13:18:28.026042+00:00    48.785346   11.344839   243
11  2014-05-06 13:18:38.027245+00:00    48.784328   11.348702   243
```

I would like to create a plot where the different `sessions` have different colors.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can change color based on columns not rows. For that you'll need to subdivide into smaller DF based on `sessions` values. i.e. `df[df['sessions']==242]`

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to avoid that but I guess is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this one is the best solution

```
groups = data.groupby('sessions')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(0.05) # Optional, just adds 5% padding to the autoscaling
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.lat, group.lon, marker='.', linestyle='', ms=12, label=name)
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```